# MS Chart Control: Drawing and Labeling Line Series Across the Chart Area

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, data-visualization, dundas

I have questions about the MS ASP.NET chart control.

1. How can a line series be set over a bar series so that it extends to the y-axis of a chart?
2. Is it possible to place the name of the line series, i.e. "Goal", to the right of the chart as a replacement to including this series in the legend?

As you can see in the screenshot below, I have a line series presenting on top of a bar series that doesn't extend to the y-axis of the chart.

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
var data1 = new Dictionary<string, float>
{
    { "W1", 80},
    { "W2", 60},
    { "W3", 40},
    { "W4", 20},
    { "W5", 10}
};
var data2 = new Dictionary<string, float>
{
    { "W1", 10},
    { "W2", 10},
    { "W3", 0},
    { "W4", 10},
    { "W5", 10}
};
var data3 = new Dictionary<string, float>
{
    { "W1", 10},
    { "W2", 30},
    { "W3", 50},
    { "W4", 70},
    { "W5", 80}
};
var data4 = new Dictionary<string, float>
{
    { "W1", 50},
    { "W2", 50},
    { "W3", 50},
    { "W4", 50},
    { "W5", 50}
};

var chart = new Chart();
chart.Height = Unit.Pixel(300);
chart.Width = Unit.Pixel(450);
chart.Legends.Add("Legend").Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
chart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None;
chart.PaletteCustomColors = new Color[] { Color.FromArgb(191, 214, 151), Color.FromArgb(249, 255, 149), Color.FromArgb(191, 79, 75), Color.Green };

var area = new ChartArea();
area.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);

var series1 = new Series("Done");
foreach (var item in data1)
{
    series1.Points.AddXY(item.Key, item.Value);
}
series1.MarkerBorderWidth = 1;

var series2 = new Series("In Progress");
foreach (var item in data2)
{
    series2.Points.AddXY(item.Key, item.Value);
}

var series3 = new Series("Needs Review");
foreach (var item in data3)
{
    series3.Points.AddXY(item.Key, item.Value);
}

var series4 = new Series("Goal");
foreach (var item in data4)
{
    series4.Points.AddXY(item.Key, item.Value);
}
series4.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series4.BorderWidth = 2;

series1.ChartType = series2.ChartType = series3.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
series1.Font = series2.Font = series3.Font = series4.Font = new Font("Verdana", 8.25f, FontStyle.Regular);

chart.Series.Add(series1);
chart.Series.Add(series2);
chart.Series.Add(series3);
chart.Series.Add(series4);
```

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:**
As I continue to search for an appropriate solution, I implemented an additional chart for just the "Goal" line series with the intentions of:

- Setting the color of certain properties of this new chart to Transparent *and*
- Laying this chart on top of the existing chart

This approach provided the correct presentation by displaying the "Goal" line series over the bar series and allowing the "Goal" line series to extend to the y-axis.  But it disabled the tooltips and the click actions of the bar series on the existing chart.  Due to this deficient user experience, this approach isn't a suitable solution.

The search for a solution continues...

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:

Another way is to use the PostPaint event, where you can draw anything you wish, anywhere on the chart... but still you lose the tooltips and such interactive features with that line.

For your question 2:

You can exclude the unwanted legend entry from the legend item collection; you can customize legend like it is done this example:

```
yourChart.CustomizeLegend += new EventHandler<CustomizeLegendEventArgs> (CustomizeLegendEventHandler);
//...
static void CustomizeLegendEventHandler(object sender, CustomizeLegendEventArgs e)
{
  int anotherIndex = 3;
  if (sender != null && sender is Chart)
  {
    if (e != null && e.LegendItems != null && e.LegendItems.Count > 0)
    {
      Chart ch = ((Chart)sender);
      if (...) //your logic here
      {
        //example: you can move a legend item from one index to another here:
        LegendItem item = e.LegendItems[0];
        e.LegendItems.RemoveAt(0);
        e.LegendItems.Insert(anotherIndex, item);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And, you can have a secondary Y axis with only one label, one point, etc. or: you can use the PostPaint event handler to draw anything you wish.

You can download a great installable sample pack from MS: [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418). They show many code examples which you can study. I found out these things from those samples and from using this new free reflector: [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).

Hope this helps.

Comment: re: your solution for question 2, will using the PostPaint event handler to draw anything that I wish also lose the tooltips and interactive features of the chart?  is it fair to assume that having a secondary Y axis won't cause this undesirable user experience?  thanks for the help.

Comment: @phreeskier: I offered this way to paint or use a empty data point on the second axis just because you didn't want that label.entry in the legend. If you use a series with one empty point you'll have interactivity - if you paint it - you won't have interactivity.
I think it's safe to assume that there will be no negative impact on user experience due to the second Y axis.